# How does tostring, concat and using the object directly have different results?

Tags: lua, coercion, havok

I'm using an version of Lua 5.1 in a game called Kingdoms of Amalur. This is havocscript but afaik, havocscript is lua. Now there is a custom type called `ui64` that the game has and a custom package that injects a hook that I added to the game.

If I do the following:

```lua
module("playerdodge_hook", package.seeall)

function save_to_file(filename, data)
    if io then
        io.output(filename)
        io.write(data)
        io.flush()
    end
end

function dodge_hook()
    local x = SIMTYPE_ID("longbow_unique11a")
    save_to_file("type", type(x))
    save_to_file("directly", x)
    save_to_file("tostring", tostring(x))
    save_to_file("concat", "" .. x)
end
```

The output of the files are the following:
type

> ui64

Directly

> Sin

tostring

> 0

concat (does not exist)

I am no expert in Lua, but i'm trying to understand how this works. As I would like to be able to print debug information and save this externally.

Edit:
Short answer is the game's engine used a proprietary override the io write method.

Amalur has different types, and the `ui64` is actually a pointer to some memory inaccessible to lua/havok script, but the library allows manipulation. And basically when a `ui64` is passed in raw to `write` calls the localization for the `Type` or `Actor` or whatever the internal object represented.

had an altered version of io library that when it received an ui64 would interrogate the

Comment: `concat` didn't work since you didn't put it in quotes, so it was parsed as a variable name.

Comment: Did you really do `save_to_file("type", x)` and not `save_to_file("type", type(x))`?

Comment: By the way, Havok Script is its own Lua-compatible VM and not "real" (PUC-Rio) Lua.

Comment: With the edit you just made to your code, do you still get the same output?

Comment: Yes. But the issue is apparently the engine had some hooks in the version of io library in the game that would pass any `ui64` type through a localization routine.

Comment: That's definitely consistent with it not being "real" Lua. You should consider expanding on that and posting it as a self-answer. (Editing answers into the question is frowned upon.)

Answer (score 2):

First, I want to say that I could not use actual `io.write` as `io` is not loaded into the engine but I have a similar method that I can use to write text to an ini entry, however, every time I call the write method it overrides the content of my personal entry regardless of if I change the key.

The basic gist of the issue is that the game Kingdoms of Amalur havok engine has a custom `write`/(and pretty much any other way to display text) routine.

The `ui64` data type is more or less a pointer to an object that exists in havok or c. However, the engine offers an api that can take these pointers and call various routines.

Passing the `ui64` to the `write` method would make the game invoke into it's localization tables and output the localized name to the screen for this particular `Type`. Thus `longbow_unique11a` is `Sin`.

Since my goal was to try to get the actual localized name and dump them all plus other data, I came up with a workaround.

Essentially, the game allows you to name crafted items, and when it does so it populates the name with a default entry and so some by decompiling some methods I was able to come up a routine to build my string like so::

```lua
function dump_item_names(tbl)
    local callback = function(text, canceled)
        op = {}
        for i = 1,#tbl do
           local actor = tbl[i]
           local typeId = get_hex_of_raw_id(actor)
           WINDOW.populate_edit_box(name_win.m_editbox, actor)
           local name = WINDOW.get_editbox_text(name_win.m_editbox)
           op[#op + 1] = typeId .. ',' .. name
        end
        save_to_file("items.txt", table.concat(op,'\n'))
    end
    name_win.launch(SL(357894144), tbl[1], true, 100, callback, false)
end
```

So yeah, not really a lua problem so much as a havok problem and me not understanding a foreign game engine that I'm hacking.